# Calculate Slope using python by ignoring null values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm new to python programming so this might be a very easy/stupid question.
Can you please help out how can I calculate Slope in python with the data below (and answer below) :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoPaI.png)

Excel basically ignores the 'blank values', how do I get the same answer using python? Please help! :)

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show the specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I have used the formula to calculate slope 
 = Slope(Known Y's,Known X's)
X = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
and Y = row from (March-Sep)

Comment: Hi Akash, welcome on SO. Please read about [how-to-ask](/helmp/how-to-ask) and [mcve](/help/mcve).

Comment: I would suggest investigating some courses on basic data science with Python. There are dozens of them out there, some decent ones for free even (or free trials).  I won't recommend any in particular here.  For example, you will find that this problem should be easy to solve with Pandas (a popular library that provides a spreadsheet-ish object called a DataFrame) and many Python data science courses teach you how to use this.